# jQuery - How can I make this work (tag replacements)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have:

```
this.html(this.html().replace(/<\/?([i-z]+)[^>]*>/gi, function(match, tag) { 
            return (tag === 'p') ? match : '<p>';
            return (tag === '/p') ? match : '</p>';
            return (tag === 'script') ? match : 'script';
            return (tag === '/script') ? match : '/script';
        }));
```

However, the `<p>` and `<script>` tags are still being removed, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: seems like a bad idea to manipulate html with regexp like that...

Comment: Just ran your code, pointed it back to itself to reference $("body") not "this".

raised an alert for tag and match.

I get a tag for /p that isnt /p for /p it comes out as "p".

and the tag for script was coming out as "s"

have I got something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am pretty sure of this now, the regex doesnt work for closing tags, and only looking for i-z isnt catching the full tag.

Try the regex of:

`/<\(/?[a-z]+)[^>]*>/gi`

something odd happens with the code though when trying to return '<script>' when matching script so in these cases maybe `return match`

Andy E's head's suggestion of changing the if statement structure I think helps too, the main thing is the

```
    else 
        return match;
```

or even do this as a default instead of specifically looking for p and script tags, it will return the match value  of the matched tag if no if statement is met.

Code I wrote for testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<div id="manipulate">
<p>Hello</p>
<script type="text/ecmascript">
// test
</script>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/ecmascript"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("start");
$("#manipulate").html($("#manipulate").html().replace(/<\/?([a-z]+)[^>]*>/gi, function(match, tag) { 
            alert(tag);
            alert(match);
        if (tag === 'p') 
            return '<p>';
        else if (tag === '/p')
            return '</p>';
        else if (tag === 'script') 
            return match;
        else if (tag === '/script') 
            return match;
        else 
            return match;
        }));
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1, didn't see the [i-z] bit at all, my attention got drawn by those ternary operators :-)

Comment: @Andy: shame you cannot make a combined correct answer so everyone involved gets points.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use multiple return statements with ternary operators like that.  The first one will be evaluated and all the rest will be ignored.  Use proper `if` statements or a `switch` statement,

```
        if (tag === 'p') 
            return '<p>';
        else if (tag === '/p')
            return '</p>';
        else if (tag === 'script') 
            return 'script';
        else if (tag === '/script') 
            return '/script';
        else 
            return match;
```

`switch` example:

```
switch (tag) {
    case 'p': return '<p>';
    case '/p': return '</p>';
    //...
    case default: return match;
}
```

You could also use an object as a map,

```
var map { 'p': '<p>', '/p' : '</p>' /*, ... */ };
return map[tag] || match;
```

or nested ternary operators,

```
return tag === 'p' ? '<p>' 
       : tag === '/p' ? '</p>'
       : tag === 'script' ? '<script>'
       : tag === '/script' ? '</script>'
       : match;
```

But these are often less readable and harder to maintain.

Comment: Or you might want to use a switch statement for your multiple if / else if / else construction - I guess that's just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @Ken, yes that's another option and I've added an example.

Comment: Couldn't you reduce a lot of duplication by having an array `['p','script']`, and only wrapping the variable in `<>` if it matches `x` or `/x`? Just seems like `p` and `script` get written a lot there..

Comment: @Jeriko: of course you could, but I don't want to do *all* the work ;-)